# How to delete folders in sdcard of file explorer?

Tags: android

I created several folders in the sdcard (Eclipse) by running an Android application in the emulator. Now I want to delete the folders which I have created on the sdcard.

I am able to delete files in the folders but I could not delete the folders in the sdcard.

How can I do this? Is there a way to delete folders?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Using adb command you can delete folders.

> click Run - > CMD-> type adb shell --> cd sdcard -> rmdir {dirname}

Note : Make sure your dir should be empty.

For non-empty directory use.

> click Run - > CMD-> type adb shell --> cd sdcard -> rm -r {dirname}

Comment: well, thanx.. this works fine to some extent..! I got a msg which says "rmdir failed for SyncFiles, Directory not empty"
Can you help please.? ("SyncFiles" is folder name on my sdcard)

Answer (score 38):

Well, answer from [Brijesh Thakur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898459/brijesh-thakur) is really helpful.

I just tried this and it worked fine for me to some extent.  I would like to mention that if your directory contains any files then the `rmdir` command will not work. You will have to use `rm -r` command for that.

To make it more easy for beginners I am explaining the process as follows.

1. First you need to locate your adb folder, mine was at `D:\Android SDK\platform-tools>`
2. Now execute `adb shell` in a command prompt as:

   ```
   D:\Android SDK\platform-tools>adb shell
   ```
3. A hash (#) symbol or dollar sign ($) will appear, then enter the following command:

   ```
   # cd sdcard
   ```
4. Now you are in the sdcard of the device. If your folder is a sub folder then further locate its parent folder using the `cd` command.  Finally, use the `rm -r` command to remove the folder recursively as follows. This will delete all files and directories in the folder.

   ```
   # rm -r FolderName
   ```

Please note that if you want to remove a single file you can use the `rm` command only and then the file name (with extension probably).  And you can also use `rmdir` command if the directory you trying to delete is empty.

Comment: If folder name contains spaces it must be escaped with backslash like this: `folder\ with\ spaces`

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to do it together with "su" yet in a batch file? I tried adb shell "su -c rm -r -f THE_PATH" but it didn't work as it complains about the "-r".

Answer (score 12):

Using `adb shell` with `rm` command you can delete(nonempty as well as empty) folders.

```
click Run -- > CMD--> type adb shell --> cd sdcard --> rm -r {dirname}
```

Answer (score 9):

We can do it in a single command line as under:

```
adb shell rm -r sdcard/<dirname>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete everything in your android file system, you need to get its storage name from adb!

```
# adb shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

It will give you the path where everything is stored!It will print the storage name in command line, for few devices it is /sdcard and for few, it is /storage/emulated/legacy etc 
Now you want to delete everything in that, you need

```
# adb shell rm -r /sdcard/
```

that `/sdcard/` is not same for all devices, it could be `/storage/emulated/legacy/` for some devices!

warning-: It will delete every folder in your file manager except "android" folder

now if you want to delete a particular folder in that file manager

```
# adb shell rm -r /sdcard/FolderName
```

Comment: You might want to add that it could be easier for control to just go `adb shell` so you can cd around and see what's there

Answer (score 0):

1. remount the sdcard with read and write permission:
   **adb shell mount -o remount,rw /**
2. Go to adb shell:
   **adb shell**
3. Delete file you want:
   **rm -r /sdcard/file_name**

It will work most better.